# Is there a notification history?

Tags: release-freya, notifications

Sometimes I get a notification, but I'm not looking at the screen, so I miss the contents of that notification. Is there a (beautiful and graphical) place where I can review all the content of the notification bubbles that pop up in the top right corner?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the moment there is not. However, it is a feature that is currently being worked on for the next release of elementary OS :)

Comment: Maybe worth writing about how can **test** the new indicators?

Comment: @PNG I think that might be a whole new question of its own tbh